# Get types of Postgres query result without executing query

Tags: database, postgresql, types

Given a running Postgres cluster, how do I get an array of type names for the columns of an arbitrary query result? I'd prefer to avoid executing the query since the queries might be prepared meaning I can't run the queries without specifying concrete values for the prepared expressions.

**Example schema**

```sql
CREATE TYPE book_type AS ENUM ('FICTION', 'NONFICTION');

CREATE TABLE books (
  book_id   SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  book_type book_type NOT NULL DEFAULT 'FICTION'
);
```

How do I get the type names of the columns for the returned rows for the following query?

```sql
SELECT book_id,
       book_type,
       'arbitrary_column',
       '2021-01-14'::date - INTERVAL '3 hour'
FROM books
WHERE book_id = $1;
```

The expected type names for the above query are:

```sql
['int', 'varchar', 'varchar', 'timestamp']
```

Is this possible via SQL? If not, is there an extension or C function? I know the types are returned when executing a query, but I'd like to know if it's possible to get the types without executing the query.

**Related**

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75015/query-to-output-names-and-data-types-of-a-query-table-or-view - Provides an answer by creating a temp table using the query and then introspecting the table. Clever and it works, but requires executing the query.

Comment: SQL Server has [`sp_describe_first_result_set`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-describe-first-result-set-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15). I have no idea if Postgres has something similar.

Comment: I think you can do this through JDBC

Answer (score 0):

Here's 3 steps that work but it does require executing the query. This is okay in my case but doesn’t answer the question generally.

1. Prepare the query, optionally adding a `LIMIT 0` or  `WHERE false` clause to make sure the query doesn't do anything.

   ```
   PREPARE sample_query AS
     SELECT book_id,
           book_type,
           'arbitrary_column'                     AS third,
           '2021-01-14'::date - INTERVAL '3 hour' AS fourth
     FROM books
     WHERE book_id = $1
     LIMIT 0;
   ```
2. Create a temp table by executing the prepared query, using `null` for all parameters.

   ```
   CREATE TEMP TABLE tmp_sample 
     AS EXECUTE sample_query ( NULL );
   ```
3. Introspect the temp table to get the return types of the original query.

   ```sql
   SELECT attname, format_type(atttypid, atttypmod) AS type
   FROM pg_attribute
   WHERE attrelid = 'tmp_sample'::regclass
     AND attnum > 0
     AND NOT attisdropped
   ORDER BY attnum;
   ```

   ```
   +---------+---------------------------+
   |attname  |type                       |
   +---------+---------------------------+
   |book_id  |integer                    |
   |book_type|book_type                  |
   |third    |text                       |
   |fourth   |timestamp without time zone|
   +---------+---------------------------+
   ```

One possible wrinkle is that all column names must be unique. A query can contain duplicate column names but a table cannot. This means you can only have 1 unnamed column because unnamed columns always use the name `?column?`.

My original reason for not executing the query was because I didn't want to figure out how to generate expressions for each prepared parameter type. Since `null` works for all types we can use it unconditionally for each prepared parameter.

Comment: That's cheating - you are executing the query. But I don't think there is a different way to do it in SQL. Some client APIs have ways to describe the result set of a statement.

Comment: Yes, definitely cheating; I’ll make that clearer in the answer. The reason this okay for my specific use case is because I can use null for any expression in the prepared statement. This approach is potentially dangerous if running on a prod database but my plan is to run these on empty test databases. I need the types to support code generation similar to sqlc.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible for programming languages with a reasonable implementation of `Prepare` in the Postgres driver.

When you run `prepare`, the Postgres wire protocol returns the OIDs of the result columns, similar to the parse step of the [extend query protocol](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/protocol-flow.html#PROTOCOL-FLOW-EXT-QUERY).

In the Go pgx library, the [Prepare](https://github.com/jackc/pgx/blob/0cc4c14e620d484d555f2955fb39cfecea89aaa3/conn.go#L298) method returns the parameter OIDS as part of the `StatementDescription` type.

In Java, JDBC's PreparedStatement.[getMetaData](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html#getMetaData--)().[getColumnType](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/ResultSetMetaData.html#getColumnType-int-)() looks like it returns the OID.

Once we have the OIDs, we can use the [pg_type](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/catalog-pg-type.html) Postgres catalog table to find the rest of the type information.

For example, to find the details of an array type:

```sql
SELECT
  arr_typ.oid           AS oid,
  -- typename: Data type name.
  arr_typ.typname::text AS type_name,
  elem_typ.oid          AS elem_oid,
  -- typtype: b for a base type, c for a composite type (e.g., a table's
  -- row type), d for a domain, e for an enum type, p for a pseudo-type,
  -- or r for a range type.
  arr_typ.typtype       AS type_kind
FROM pg_type arr_typ
  JOIN pg_type elem_typ ON arr_typ.typelem = elem_typ.oid
WHERE arr_typ.typisdefined
  AND arr_typ.typtype = 'b' -- Array types are base types
  -- If typelem is not 0 then it identifies another row in pg_type. 
  AND arr_typ.typelem > 0
  -- For a fixed-size type, typlen is the number of bytes in the internal
  -- representation of the type. But for a variable-length type, typlen is
  -- negative. -1 indicates a "varlena" type (one that has a length word), -2
  -- indicates a null-terminated C string.
  AND arr_typ.typlen = -1
  AND arr_typ.oid = ANY ('{1}'::oid[]);
```